# Filed to complete Gradle execution

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Поставил чистую систему Linux(Ubuntu)

Установил jdk,android studio и сразу же после создания нового проекта вылезла ошибка

> > Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>
> Cause: Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 2

Ничего не меня в файлах конфигураций, установил Android Support Repository..не помогло

Сам build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.root.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Вот вроде похожая проблема с решением: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27407855/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-cause-is-empty

Comment: Да, но мне варианты которые там не подошли